# unable to marshal type "[B" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation

Tags: java, xml, rest-assured

I was trying to send xml data after converting to `UTF-16` encoding format and sending to put endpoint but seeing below exception.

```java
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "[B" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.LeafBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(LeafBeanInfoImpl.java:142)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:328)
    ... 99 more
```

I'm using rest-assured as a client.

could someone please help me...

Comment: so ... add that annotation to the class B.

Comment: that is in byte[]

Comment: what do you mean "that is in byte[]"? anyway, if that class doesn't have that annotation, you can't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm saying I have a string in XML format, encoded that to UTF-16, and sent to some put endpoint, with contentType as `application/xml` and I do not receive the request as it is failing to convert that byte array into xml

Comment: and I've already said: the reason that can't be done, is because on the class you are trying to convert it to, there is no @XmlRootElement annotation. Add that, and it'll work.